# How to update an array inside an array of objects with useState function component

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, use-state

How to update array inside array use state function component
the array is inside the `setTask()` and how to use `setTask()` and add `new_photo` in photos

```
const new_photo = "testing2.png"; <------------ insert this value in photos

const [task, setTask] = useState([
    {
        task_id: 123,
        title: "sample",
        photos: ["testing1.png"] <------------ here
    }
])
```

Result should be like this:

```
[
    {
        task_id: 123,
        title: "sample",
        photos: ["testing1.png","testing2.png"]
    }
]
```

Comment: Hi vince - please can you share what you have tried so far and what isn't working with your current code? It also isn't very clear how you decide which object to add `"testing2.png"` when your array has multiple objects. Do you want it to be added to all objects in your array, or just one with a specific id...? It would be good if you can please [edit] your question to include all of this information

Comment: done sir, sorry its my first time asking question here

Comment: Unfortunately, your edit didn't add any of the information that was asked for in the first comment. As this is your first time asking a question, please see [ask] to get some details on asking questions - the main things that your question is missing is: 1. Your attempt at solving this yourself (this shows that you've tried something and that you're not asking other people to "do your job for you"), and 2. Further clarification about how you pick which object to update, eg: What happens when you have data that looks like: `[{ task_id: 123, ...}, { task_id: 456, ...} ]` (ie: multiple objects)

Comment: I understand that showing what you have tried might be difficult if you don't know where to start - If that's the case, you can share some links to other questions on here or other articles that you have tried but haven't worked for you. This shows that you've done some research to try and solve the issue yourself first, and also will allow the answerer to not repeat information you may already know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
setTask((oldTasks) => {
  const myTask = oldTasks.find(t => t.task_id === 123)
  return [
    ...oldTasks.filter(ot => ot.task_id != 123),
    {
      ...myTask,
      photos: [...myTask.photos, new_photo],
    }
  ]
})
```

Ref: [spread operator](https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_es6_spread.asp) and [asynchronous state update](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

Comment: This will find the task, but it will add a new object to the state array rather than updating the one that is there (ie: this will create two objects in the state array rather than keeping just one)

Comment: @vince.villafuerte Are you sure it works? This will output `[ { "task_id": 123, "title": "sample", "photos": [ "testing1.png" ] }, { "task_id": 123, "title": "sample", "photos": [ "testing1.png", "testing2.png" ] } ]`, so now you have your old object, along with a new one (which doesn't match what you asked for in your question)

Comment: i get the idea on your codes sir, that i should use  ". . .myTask.photos"

Answer (score 0):

```
    const new_photo = "testing2.png"; // <------------ insert this value in photos

const [task, setTask] = useState([
    {
        task_id: 123,
        title: "sample",
        photos: ["testing1.png"] // <------------ here
    }
])

const arrayPush = (ID) => {
  setTask((element) => {
    element.forEach((e) => {
      if (e.task_id === ID) {
       e.photos.push(new_photo);
     }
    });
  });
console.log(task);
}

const arrayPush2 = (ID) => {
    let taskCopy = Array.from(task)
    taskCopy.forEach((element) => {
      if (element.task_id === ID) {
        element.photos.push(new_photo);
      }
    });
    setTask(taskCopy)
};

arrayPush(123)
arrayPush2(123)
```

Comment: This will modify the `task` state directly, which you shouldn't be doing in React (`let taskCopy = task` does not create a copy)

Comment: thank you it's my mistake answer is updated please check

Comment: `element` in the callback still refers to the state object, so changing it with `e.photos.push()` still modifies the objects within the array

Comment: `let taskCopy = Array.from(task)` using array prototype it will create copy right ?

Comment: That will create a copy of the task array `[]`, but not the objects inside of it, eg: `const task = [{x: 1}]; const copy = Array.from(task); copy[0].x++; console.log(task);` would show `[{x: 2}]`. For this particular case, we need to copy three levels, the outer array `[]`, the object `{}` and the inner array `[]` (ie: we need to deep copy, the object's we're changing as opposed to a shallow copy (which is what `Array.from()` does), so the above code still modifies the original `photos` arrary from the original state